# Angular - Disable select option if value exists in array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have nesting select element in a form and I only want each value selected once. How can I check if `occupation.occupation` exists in the `selectedoccupations` array and set `[disabled]=''` to true if it exists?

component

```
  selectedOccupations: any[] = [
    { occupation: 'dev' },
  ];
```

template

```
<tr>
          <td>
            <md-select formControlName="occupation" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Occupation" (change)="filterGuests($event, i)">
              <md-option [value]="null">Occupation</md-option>
              <md-option *ngFor="let occupation of occupationz" [value]="occupation.occupation" [disabled]="">
                {{ occupation.occupation }}
              </md-option>
            </md-select>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a call to a typescript function which returns the value for you!

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <md-select formControlName="occupation" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Occupation" (change)="filterGuests($event, i)">
      <md-option [value]="null">Occupation</md-option>
      <md-option *ngFor="let occupation of occupationz" [value]="occupation.occupation" [disabled]="isDisabled(occupation)">
        {{ occupation.occupation }}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And then in typescript:

```
function isDisabled(occupation: any):boolean{
    // if it exists... disabled == true;
    return selectedOccupations.includes(occupation.occupation); // note, i'm not certain if this should just be occupation.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `[disabled] = "selectedOccupations.includes(occupation)"` ?

This isn't very efficient, but shouldn't be all that bad.